# Loading a Texture2D from middle of stream

Tags: file, xna, texture2d

I was wondering if it is possible to use the Texture2D.FromStream() in XNA to load a texture from the middle of a stream. The idea is that I have an animation system that saves the texture for the limb directly into the file that contains the other information, like timing, name, etc... My problem comes when trying to load the file, when it gets to the loading of the Texture. I get an InvalidOperationExecption, and no real detail. Here is my code so far:

Writing:

```
...         
//writes the name
binWriter.Write(name);

if (texture != null)
{
    binWriter.Write(true);
    //save the texture into the stream
    texture.SaveAsPng(binWriter.BaseStream, texture.Width, texture.Height);
}
else
    binWriter.Write(false);

//writes the ID of the parent limb
binWriter.Write(system.getParentID((Limb)parent));
...
```

Reading:

```
...
string name = binReader.ReadString();

Texture2D tex = null;

//gets the texture if it exists
bool texture = binReader.ReadBoolean();
if (texture)
    tex = Texture2D.FromStream(graphics, binReader.BaseStream);

//finds the index of the parent limb
int parentID = binReader.ReadInt32();
...
```

Any Ideas?

-Edit- Solved! I used the getData() and setData() methods, and wrote and read the data as an array of uints.

Comment: If it doesn't work, you should try copying a part of the texture with `GetData` and `SetData`.